# complete vector spaces intuition

Tags: vector-spaces, intuition

I have been reading about vector spaces and want to get an understanding of completeness in a vector space.

My undestanding of compelteness comes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space

If there are other definitions of completeness I would really appreciate anyone pointing me to it.

Based on the above definition I have a few questions:

For a space to be defined as complete, do we need a sequence of some sort? i.e., Completeness cannot be defined without a sequence? Further, this sequence needs to satisfy the closure property?

I am guessing a metric implies a set is ordered (or partially ordered)? Can anyone clarify if the set needs to be totally ordered for a metric or partially ordered?

Can I have a complete space without a metric?

Comment: Please include the definition of "complete" that you have. Writing it out in detail might answer several of these questions on its own.

Comment: I am referring to the wikipedia definiton - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space. I was not aware there can be many definiton to completeness?

Comment: Still, as I said, include it because writing it down in detail will help you.

Comment: No, don't link to it. Write it down in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, you can't leave a vector space by adding elements or performing multiplication with a scalar. (For $v,w \in V$ $v + w \in V$ and for $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, $\lambda v \in V$ if $V$ is a real vector space).

"Taking the limit" is a different operation and hence, if you have a sequence $v_n \in V$, you are not guaranteed that a limit exists, and if it exists that it lies in $V$.

This is why complete vector spaces deserve a definition of their own. Cauchy sequences are essentially sequences that converge (see the note below for more details), and the notion of completeness makes sure that their limits are in $V$. In order to determine if a sequence is a Cauchy sequence, you need (at least) a metric.

Note: If you have a metric space $V$, you can define a Cauchy sequence in the usual way. Furthermore, you can define an equivalence relation on the set of Cauchy sequences in order to define the completion of $V$, see, e.g. [here](http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/~supriya/teaching/Topology-MTH322/files/Completion.pdf). This is why I said that Cauchy sequences 'have essentially a limit'.

Answer (score 0):

Completeness is all about convergence of cauchy sequences inside the space . To study about the convergence to sequence in a space one must know the topological structure of that space so that one can define open sets, closed sets limit points and hence convergence of sequences with help of a metric.